# Port forwarding when the ISP blocks it

Tags: network, port-forwarding

I am working on establishing penetration testing service in our startup. The issue is that our ISPs is somehow blocking port forwarding. I tried to contact them in order to allow port forwarding, but they refused without knowing why I need it.

So I'm looking for a low-cost alternative solution since we are a startup. Can anyone help us, please?

Comment: Maybe VPN would be better then port mapping?

Comment: Are you not able to forward ports because you don't have a static IP (you're in a nat box) or is your ISP controlling your router in some way?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to have reverse shell through out the internet and mapping a specific port in the public IP address to a specific port in my machine's IP address, unfortunately this is not working, for the VPN alternative solution can I use any VPN or there is a specific VPN supporting such a service ?

Comment: this is in no way a security question - and you do mean 'port forwarding'

Comment: Well I'm not the one who edited it, My question was mainly on providing penetration testing service in a real world and what are the alternative solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your ISP is actually blocking ports. You could try -

1. Changing ISPs if thats feasible
2. May be upgrade to a business plan (that is still affordable).
3. Like Aria mentioned, try a VPN

Comment: Well, I think the most affordable thing for us is VPN since we only have one ISP, but I want to ask you do I need to look for a specific VPNs or any VPN can solve or issue ?